# Orao Oracle: fail to import JS SDK

Tags: node.js, oracles, solana-sdk

When loading the node module @orao-network/solana-vrf to interact with the Orao oracle, I receive this error:

*Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined
at ./node_modules/@orao-network/solana-vrf/dist/index.js*

I'm just loading the Orao library in my JS file with:

```
import {
    Orao,
    networkStateAccountAddress,
    randomnessAccountAddress,
    FulfillBuilder,
    InitBuilder,
} from "@orao-network/solana-vrf";
```

Orao resources:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@orao-network/solana-vrf/v/0.2.4

https://github.com/orao-network

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for another alternative:

Switchboard provides [VRF](https://switchboard.xyz/randomness).

Here's a basic [walkthrough](https://github.com/switchboard-xyz/vrf-demo-walkthrough) on how to use Switchboard VRF.

Here's a [demo](https://github.com/switchboard-xyz/vrf-flip) of using Switchboard VRF for a [coin flip game](https://vrf-demo.switchboard.xyz/).